# Does the Flash ever meet his younger self in the TV show, after having gone back in time?

Tags: dc, time-travel, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash* (the 2014 TV-series), we see the Flash going back in time in "Out of Time" (S1E15) while solving the tsunami issue. But we didn't see him going back to the future. So we can assume he hasn't done so yet.

So if he never made it back to the future, **does he ever meet the younger Barry Allen?**

If not, why not?

Comment: The answer is he did of course, briefly, just after his travelling back in time.

Comment: He did meet his younger self if that's what you're asking for. It is clearer in the series in the season 1 finale I think, not in the Tsunami incident.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't there two Flashes?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/why-arent-there-two-flashes)

Comment: As the answer on the other question explains, the specific instance you're referring to wasn't time travel. He *does* time travel later in the series though.

Answer (score 1):

As it explains [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84748/why-arent-there-two-flashes), Barry never travels back in time per se. At least not in that episode. He experiences "temporal reversion" where he travels so fast his consciousness is reverted back through time and he's allowed to experience the day over again.

In the season 1 finale,

> Barry does travel back in time to the moment his mother is killed and **encounters the child version of himself** from that time as well as a future version of himself that fights the Reverse Flash.

**So, to answer your question, yes. He sees the younger version of himself.** But it was completely unrelated to the events of the "Out of Time" episode.

Comment: Exactly, accurate answer. +1 !

Comment: If you're going to just use the answer from another question, mark the question as a dupe.

Comment: @phantom42 - My answer references another answer for supporting material but is not the same. The info in the spoiler tag and the bolded bit under it are the meat and potatoes of my answer.

Comment: Oh, just saw why you got a little miffed... I didn't see your comment "He does time travel later in the series though." You feel like I ripped your comment and called it an answer.

Comment: The "meat and potatoes" of your answer have nothing to do with the question. OP is asking about the version specifically from the tsunami incident.

Comment: I have no issues with people turning my comments into answers. If I wanted it to be an answer, I would have written it as one.